# is there a way to test google data feed? not sure what to make of these errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, google-api

It's on 2 different htmls in the site and it's not working on any of the various versions of the site I have done. Is it in my coding or is there an issue with the feed or WHAT?? please help!!

http://www.clockshop.org/calendar.html

these are the errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   Uncaught TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have 2 different javascript errors at your page: In your main.js you're calling the function `waypoint()` which is not declared. You have to download waypoint.js and include it before the include of the main.js. Then there's 
`document.getElementById('jsSourceFinal').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');`
throwing an error because the element with the id `jsSourceFinal` does not exist.
This is also called in your main.js by the `function handleGDError(e) {}` which is a callback function for the Google data JS client library.
In addition, the `loadCalendar('https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds...')` at the end of your HTML does not work because this url gets the server response `403 forbidden`.

Comment: thank you so much, matthias. i tried this and it gets rid of the waypoint error but that's not the error throwing off the google calendar... any other suggestions? if you go to the index.html page and make it mobile, the calendar should show up there as well and it's throwing the same error - so it's not specific to one html page. also, i have maybe 10 older versions of this site and the calendar no longer works on any of them - so i feel it has to do something with the feed changing?

Comment: @judith, was just about to update the answer as you also have the problem that the include of the feed doesn't work; the include of https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/m00bjts7fdqj3d7jqksqamqouc%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full at the end of your html has the server response `403 forbidden`

Comment: exactly - thank you so much. but why wouldn't work? im not even sure how to troubleshoot for that. there has been no purposeful change to the settings of the calendar. what could the issue be? is it possible google changed something and how do i figure that out? thank you - i really appreciate your help.this is the xml feed of the calendar if it helps: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/m00bjts7fdqj3d7jqksqamqouc%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic

Comment: ah ha!! but ughhhh -- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol -- "This API is a subject to the Deprecation Policy and will be shutdown on November 17, 2014. Please use APIv3 instead. "

Comment: @judith ok :) than you'll have to adjust to the new api. I just thought it could be because the url you mentioned in the comments ends with ../basic (works) instead of ../full (403 error) and you're including the /full on your page.

Comment: that's actually how i discovered the problem. as i pasted in the html i saw that it worked, but your link didn't, and then googling basic vs full brought me to the page saying that today it is shutdown - while before googling all sort of "google feed error" didn't lead me anywhere. it's all about the right search terms. anyways, glad to be on the right track! thank you so much.

Comment: @judith Glad I was able to be of help and hopefully it won't take you too much time to adjust to the new api.

Answer (score 1):

The feed is not working because "This API is a subject to the Deprecation Policy and will be shutdown on November 17, 2014. Please use APIv3 instead." developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/… -- "